# Kafka streams Exception: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException - Deserialization exception handler

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I am trying to implement a simple counter with kafka streams. It takes a key value and adds new values if the same key comes.

This is the code I wrote so far

```
package exercises;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;

import java.util.Properties;

public class LiveCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "live-counter-2");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.LongSerde.class.getName());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> textLine = builder.stream("counter-in");

        KStream<String, Long> words = textLine
                .filter((k, v) -> {
                    try {
                        String[] arr = v.split(" ");
                        Long.parseLong(arr[1]);
                        return true;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .selectKey((k, v) -> v.split(" ")[0])
                .mapValues((k, v) -> Long.parseLong(v.split(" ")[1]))
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce(Long::sum)
                .toStream();
        words.to("counter-out", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        streams.start();

        System.out.println(streams.toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
}
```

As we can see the topology is simple. It takes a textline and changes the key and then finally adds all the values for key groups with the reduce function.

I tried streaming until mapValues and it was working. But this code block is causing the problem

```
.groupByKey()
.reduce(Long::sum)
.toStream();
```

This is the stacktrace

```
live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler - Exception caught during Deserialization, taskId: 0_0, topic: counter-in, partition: 0, offset: 1
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:765)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:943)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:764)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67] State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67] All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
[live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
Exception in thread "live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:765)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:943)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:764)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:697)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:670)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
[Thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67] State transition from ERROR to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
[kafka-streams-close-thread] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to NOT_RUNNING
[Thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [live-counter-2-9a694aa5-589d-4d2f-8e1c-ff64b6e05b67] Streams client stopped completely
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input topic, `counter-in`, consists of messages that are `String`s, and your default value serializer is `LongSerde`, you need to tell Kafka Streams to deserialize the value as a string as follows:

```
KStream<String, String> textLine = builder.stream("counter-in", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That had solved my problem. Could you please tell at what all cases we have to specify serdes? It’s very confusing especially when the data type is changing in the stream. I know that Serdes should be specified at group by and while writing to output topic

Comment: @Bharat my rule of thumb is to always specify the key and value serdes.

Comment: In depends on the version you are using. In older version, what @ck1 says it's right: An operator used the serdes from the config if not overwritten. -- In newer version, Kafka Streams is smarter and key/value Serdes propagate downstream as not as the the key/value is not changes. For example, `filter()` does not change the key or value and thus the upstream serde "flows" downstream. `selectKey()` changes the key but not the value; hence downstream operator fall back to the config for the key serde (if not set again) but reuse the upstream value serde.